Power Automate Foreach 501 items limit
I am trying to loop through parsed json elements to write data to a variable, that will be sent as a CSV.
Unfortunately, the loops stop looping at 501 items :



Others flows are doing the same thing sucessfully, having less than 500 item !
From what i seen online, the loop have a 5k elements limits.
Why would it stop at 501 items precisely each time ?
Thank you !

Are you sure there are more than 501 items in your JSON? Why are you looping? Can't you go direct from JSON to CSV via the "Create CSV table" action?

Well, i just find out that the DAX query i use for the dataset request have a TOPN filter that is not supposed to be there (i guess it is here because i copied DAX from a table visual and that limit might be to optimize visual rendering) ! So you were right ! Thank you for the lead :)
Will post detail under

Do note the DAX action can only return 1,000 rows.

With the correction of the TOPN element in the DAX query, i was able to get all the 3000 rows into my CSV !

Thanks to the suggestion of @Sam Nseir
Problem was not on the loop itself but on the dataset request.
Since i used a DAX request from a table visual in Power BI desktop, i did not noticed that it included a TOPN 501 limitation.
Corrected request allow to take 5000 elements look like this :
    VAR __DS0PrimaryWindowed = 
    TOPN(
        5000,
        __DS0Core,

That way everything worked fine !
Thank you !
